# ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class App\Http\Controllers\classroom does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

Last night i upload my laravel 5.2 project in live server. 
When i upload this i face this error my classroom controller does not exit. But in localhost it's working nice with no error.
My classroom controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\classroom;
//use App\Http\Controllers\controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Eloquent\Status;
use App\Eloquent\joinclass;

use App\Eloquent\StatusComments;
use App\Eloquent\announcement;
use Laracasts\Flash\Flash;
use DB;
use Session;
//use App\Model\classrooms;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\classroom as classroomModel;
use App\Http\Requests;
use View;
use App\User;
```

Why show me this errors?

Comment: I think you would need to remove the last `classroom` in namespace like this `namespace App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: bro i do that at first... but not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will definitely work if everything is fine and still you get this error just run following command in your terminal

```
cd /path_of_root_folder_where_composer_json_is_located
```

then run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

it will work try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\classroom;
use App\Http\Controllers\controller;
```

replace with

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Classroom;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```